# Thread synchronization design

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, critical-section

I have a class in my project which contains 4 vectors

```
m_vecA;
m_vecB;
m_vecC;
m_vecD;
```

These vectors can be accessed in different threads.I can use one critical section and protect all these vectors with it.

Or is it good idea to have 4 critical sections one for each resource? If I use one critical section for all resources I am seeing deadlock issue.

Generally is it good design to have one critical section for one resource or can we have one critical section per class?

Comment: One nitpick. A critical section is not for a resource - the critical section is the ACCESS to that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have 4 critical sections, but:

The trick is to always access (lock) them in the same order,

```
say A then B then C then D
```

Otherwise you can deadlock if:

```
thread one locks A and is waiting for B,

and thread 2 locks B and is waiting on A
```

This cannot happen if you enforce a critical section ordering

Comment: @polkadotcadaver I think it's still good general rule of thumb advice though!

Answer (score 2):

You should have one critical section for each item that needs to be accessed simultaneously.

Basically, a critical section for all four would mean that if one is locked by one thread, none of them can be read or written by other threads. A critical section for each would mean up to four threads could access them all at the same time.

Comment: You can avoid deadlock by introducing a locking order. If you keep a lock to something, then you should acquire lock with higher ordering number. If all locks are released then you can lock anything again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 separate, independent resources, and it doesn't matter what they contain in relationship to each other, you probably want to protect them separately and independently.

However, if those 4 vectors, together, represent a single logical resource, and they must always be updated atomically and stay valid with respect to each other, you'll want to protect them as a group.

> Or is it good idea to have 4 critical sections one for each resource?
>   If I use one critical section for all resources I am seeing deadlock
>   issue.

As was mentioned in other answers, this will happen if you threads are locking more than one resource at a time and are not always locking them in the *same order*.

Keep in mind that if threads *always* need to lock all four vectors to work with them, you don't want to protect them individually, but as a single group.

> Generally is it good design to have one critical section for one
>   resource or can we have one critical section per class?

This again depends on whether each vector represents a completely independent resource, or whether all 4 vectors, as a group, are a single logical resource. The fact that you have put them in a class together seems to indicate the latter. If this is true, you should thus have a single lock protecting all of them as a group.